# Prevent Double click on addtocart button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I am using this code for `addtocart`

my code is like this which is working fine, except that I am getting the item added twice when double clicking, How I can fix this?

```
<?php 
    if (!in_array(strtotime($timeslot), $slots)){ ?>
    <div  style="margin-top:2%;text-align: center;margin-left: -10px" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <span class="btn btn-danger mylabel"  onclick="addToCart(<?=$timing['id']?>,'<?=$timeslot?>',<?=$values['id']?>,<?=$values->instructor->manager['location_id']?>)"  id="btntime<?=$timing['id'] ?>">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" id="time<?=$timing['id']?>" name="time" value="<?=$timing['id']?>"  >

<?php  echo date('h:i', strtotime($timeslot)) . '- ' . date('h:i A', strtotime($endTime)); ?>

     </span>
    </div>
    <?php     }?>
```

update:

```
xhr:http://testing.com/reservation/add2cart?id=346&url=reservation&instructor_id=147&location_id=1&start_time=10:20:00&date1=2019-04-17
xhr:http://testing.com/reservation/reservation?location=1&date1=2019-04-17
xhr:http://testing.com/reservation/reservation?location=1&date1=2019-04-17
```

updated code as suggested by 
Muhammad Omer Aslam

```
<?php 
if (!in_array(strtotime($timeslot), $slots)){ ?>
<div  style="margin-top:2%;text-align: center;margin-left: -10px" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<span 
class="btn btn-danger mylabel" 
data-cart="<?php echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode(['timing_id'=>$timing['id'], 'timeslot'=>$timeslot, 'values_id'=>$values['id'], 'manager_location_id'=>$values->instructor->manager['location_id']])?>" 
id="btntime<?=$timing['id'] ?>">
<input type="radio" class="radio-inline" id="time<?=$timing['id']?>" name="time" value="<?=$timing['id']?>"  >

<?php      echo date('h:i', strtotime($timeslot)) . '- ' . date('h:i A', strtotime($endTime)); ?>

</span>
</div>
<?php } ?>      

<?php
  }

 }
} else {
?>

<label>Staff is on holiday</label>
 <?php
  }
}
} else {
?> <label style="text-align:center">Today this instructor is not available</label>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

and just on top of the page:

```
<?php
use app\models\User;
use app\modules\admin\models\ClassDuration;
use app\modules\admin\models\OrderItem;
use app\modules\admin\models\Location;
use app\modules\admin\models\Manager;
use app\modules\admin\models\WorkingDays;
//$cart_value = \Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('order_item');
//var_dump($cart_value);
$js=<<<JS
    $(document).on('click','span.mylabel',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).css({pointerEvents:'none'});
         let cart_params= $(this).data('cart');
         addToCart(cart_params.timing_id,cart_params.timeslot, cart_params.values_id, cart_params.manager_location);
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);


$session = Yii::$app->session;
$cart_value= $session['value'];
//var_dump($session['value']);
$st = Yii::$app->getTable;
$url = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
```

Comment: use a button and disable it when `addToCart` is called. Button should probably also be disabled if item is already in cart.

Comment: so you are trying to **disable** click once you have clicked on it?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, no disable the button

Comment: and then when to enable it ? never?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam when `addToCart` is complete

Comment: @Joshi you might need to provide `addToCart` looks to be an ajax call ? is it?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam im not the OP, im just answering the question.

Comment: oops :D i never bothered @IsaacVidrine

Comment: Hi Omer - Yes it is Ajax, I have updated the question the call shown in the console. do you need any other info.

Comment: what i am trying to understand is that you want to disallow an item to be added more than once or you are just trying to control an accidental double-click

Comment: Yes Omer you are absolutely right, what I want is to simply disallow an item to be added twice or you can say more than once, as my item are time slots, so slot can be booked once only, but if you accidentally double click, it is adding the slots twice to the cart.

Comment: added an answer see if it helps you out

Comment: can you confirm if there are any errors on the console when you click on the `addToCart` button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the CSS property `pointerEvents` for the button, and set its value to `none` that would do it and disallow clicking on the button once it is clicked.

Now the second thing is how to call it, I would recommend making a few changes to your code, and bind the click function to the element via jquery and remove the inline `onclick` attribute.

For the parameters that you are passing, adjust them to the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) for the element.

Change your span HTML to the following

```
<span 
 class="btn btn-danger mylabel" 
 data-cart='<?php echo \yii\helpers\Json::encode(['timing_id'=>$timing['id'], 'timeslot'=>$timeslot, 'values_id'=>$values['id'], 'manager_location_id'=>$values->instructor->manager['location_id']])?>' 
 id="btntime<?=$timing['id'] ?>">
```

and then bind the click via jquery by adding this snippet on the top of the view.

```
$js=<<<JS
    $(document).on('click','span.mylabel',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

        //this disables the clicking any further
         $(this).css({pointerEvents:'none'});

         // get the dynamic params fromt he dataset
         let cart_params= $(this).data('cart');

         //send them as params to the cart method
         addToCart(cart_params.timing_id,cart_params.timeslot, cart_params.values_id, cart_params.manager_location_id);
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Hi Omer - tried your code, but the item is not getting added to cart, I am getting alert like please select time.

Comment: can you show your code after integrating the changes by editing in your question? @Joshi

Comment: Hi Omer - I have included the changes and updated the question.

Comment: @joshi just do one thing and check if it works by replacing the double quote `"` surrounding the value for the `data-cart` tag with the single quote `'`, that must be what I suspect is the error as the `JSON` also includes the double quotes for the property names. and currently we are using `data-cart="<?php echo JSON::encode()?>"` whereas it should be `data-cart='<?php echo JSON::encode()?>'`

Comment: Hi Omer - perfect, replacing double quote with single quote did the trick.

Comment: @Joshi i suspected so, good to know it works now. Cheers. and i have updated the code in the answer too.

Comment: Hi Omer - just observed, there is still a small issue, like in the cart I have cols - location, instructor,date- from the modified code, location col info I am getting blank in the cart.

Comment: @Joshi verify in the html source code if the `json` in the `data-cart` has the value populated ? otherwise verify `$values->instructor->manager['location_id']` if it is correctly retrieving value as this is used as `cart_params.manager_location` for the `addToCart` method's last parameter which i think you are referring to

Comment: @Joshi it actually should be `cart_params.manager_location_id` instead of `cart_params.manager_location` in the javascript code as the last parameter , my bad sorry for that

Comment: just updated the javscript code too in the answer it should work correctly now

Comment: Hi Omer - Thanks I was able to fix that. you have json key as ''manager_location_id'` but in the Js it is `manager_location` only. I modified the key to `manager_location` only and it worked.

Comment: yes that was the mistake i pointed out in my last message, sorry for that, hope it works now, cheers @Joshi

Answer (score -1):

**You can disable it with JavaScript**

```
onClick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Added to cart';"
```

Added to your code:

```
<?php 
    if (!in_array(strtotime($timeslot), $slots)){ ?>
    <div  style="margin-top:2%;text-align: center;margin-left: -10px" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <span class="btn btn-danger mylabel"  onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Added to cart'; addToCart(<?=$timing['id']?>,'<?=$timeslot?>',<?=$values['id']?>,<?=$values->instructor->manager['location_id']?>)"  id="btntime<?=$timing['id'] ?>">
    <input type="radio" class="radio-inline" id="time<?=$timing['id']?>" name="time" value="<?=$timing['id']?>"  >

<?php  echo date('h:i', strtotime($timeslot)) . '- ' . date('h:i A', strtotime($endTime)); ?>

     </span>
    </div>
    <?php     }?>
```

Comment: No, It's now working. I am still getting the item added twice on dblclick.

Answer (score -1):

I would have that onclick javascript disable the button. Using jquery:

```
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
```